# Progress bar not showing with networkD3 and Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, progress-bar, htmlwidgets, networkd3

I have some issues with progress bars in Shiny and the package `networkD3`. The progress bar shows up fine without trying to render a diagram from that package. If try to use a progress bar and the `networkD3` package, the bar shows up once but not in subsequent calls. I tested in Chrome. Here is a minimum example code:

```
require(shinyjs)
require(shiny)
require(networkD3)
require(jsonlite)

ui <- function(){
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(width = 12, style = "margin: 0px; padding: 0px;",
             box(title = "Flow Diagram", status = "primary", solidHeader = F, width = 7,
                 sankeyNetworkOutput("sankeyFlow", width = "100%", height = "500px")
             )
      ), 
      sliderInput("numLanes", label = "Number of Top Lanes", min = 0, max = 30, value = 10)
    )
  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(c(input$numLanes), {
    withProgress(message = "Wait...", value = NULL, {
      Sys.sleep(1.0)
    })
  })

  output$sankeyFlow <- renderSankeyNetwork({
    print("sankey")

    withProgress(message = "Updating flow diagram...", value = NULL, {

      # Load energy projection data
      URL <- "https://cdn.rawgit.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/master/JSONdata/energy.json"
      Energy <- jsonlite::fromJSON(URL)

      nLanes <- input$numLanes

      plot <- sankeyNetwork(Links = Energy$links, Nodes = Energy$nodes, Source = "source",
                                  Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
                                  units = "TWh", fontSize = 12, nodeWidth = 30)
      return(plot)
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Maybe someone has some insight on why this is happening and a possible workaround. In my use case I use several progress bars and none are displayed if I include the flow diagram.

Thanks,
Christian

Comment: Just one observation, `Sys.sleep()` and shiny do not play well together, use `invalidateLater` instead.

Comment: Your minimal example code is not working for me. I had to remove the box(). Beside this, the code works good. You have on progress bar box when changing the input and another one on top when the plot is rendering. However since, you don't reset they just appear on the first load. What do you want to archive exactly?

Comment: @AlexanderLeow What exactly do you mean by reset? The progress bar should be shown each time the input slider is changed. If you try commenting out output$sankeyFlow this is the behaviour I see and what I am aming for. If the diagram is active if only shows once.

Comment: @Cbac, now I got what you mean. There I tried different things but can not solve your issue. The sankeyNetwork is producing a deprecation warning (look to the console) which seems to corrupt the progress bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is a conflict/bug with how `networkD3` enables tooltips with multiple lines in `sankeyNetwork()`.

see...
https://github.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/issues/250

---

**UPDATE (2019-05-20)**

This issue has been resolved with the dev version of `shiny` and should be released on CRAN soon as `shiny v1.3.3`.